# Property is nil when accessed from other class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, nsdata

I have two classes, a subclass of NSDocument (Class A) and a subclass of NSView (Class B). In my NSView subclass, after all the drawing is done, I save the view into a NSData. In Class B drawRect:

```
self.viewData = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[self bounds]]TIFFRepresentation];
```

Setting a breakpoint on the next line shows the value :

```
_viewData   OS_dispatch_data *  1003522 bytes   0x0000618000069cc0
```

However, in dataOfType:error: in Class A, the following line: (note that Class B is named theCanvas here)

```
return [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[theCanvas viewData]]representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
```

results in an error:

> ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil

And a breakpoint in that method shows that viewData is nil:

```
_viewData   NSData *    nil 0x0000000000000000
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is `theCanvas` the same instance that the viewData was actually saved on?

Comment: It should be. The variable is set in drawRect: in the .m source file- so it should be part of any instance. Also, there is only supposed to be one instance of that particular view. Still, I'll look into it… anything is better than homework(:

Comment: I know you have an instance and it is working but that doesn't mean that `theCanvas` is pointing to the instance that you are working with. Where you set `self.viewData` do `NSLog(@"%@", self);` and then see if this is the same object as when you `NSLog(@"%@" theCanvas);`

Comment: While I'll be darned. It IS different. How did… OH I have it in both code and XIB. oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that `theCanvas` actually points to the instance of your class where you know the data is being set correctly. The likelihood is that you have two different instances of the same class.